# Swift how to change tintColor of backIndicatorImage

Tags: ios, swift

I have got this code in AppDelegate
U

```
INavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "backarrow")
```

And even though the image's color is white it shows it as blue.How can i change the tintcolor of this image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to `Assets.xcassets`
2. Select your image `backarrow`
3. Show the `Attributes Inspector`
4. Change `Render As` value form `Default` to `Original Image`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5.x & Xcode 12 Solution**:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "abc")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = image
navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = image
```