# iOS 11 UINavigationBar Back button image color issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uinavigationbar, ios11

I am facing issue in iOS 11 with custom BackButton Image color.

BackButton Image works correct in versions lower the iOS 11.

I have customized the Back Button Image of `UINavigationBar` by using following code.

```
            [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:false];

    UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 5.0f, 0);
    UIImage *backArrowImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_nav_back"] imageWithAlignmentRectInsets:insets];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorImage:backArrowImage];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorTransitionMaskImage:backArrowImage];
```

It displays a proper image with default color of image in versions lower than iOS11

[image]

But, In Version iOS 11 its color and size have been improper.

[image]

Please provide proper solution to resolve this issue.

I have tried Tint Color also, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Check this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28733936/change-color-of-back-button-in-navigation-bar

Comment: @Damo I have tried all of these solutions. It doesn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link: [Swift how to change tintColor of backIndicatorImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45564632/swift-how-to-change-tintcolor-of-backindicatorimage)

set image on this method `setBackIndicatorTransitionMaskImage` Might be help!

```
[UINavigationBar appearance].translucent = NO;
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorImage:backArrowImage];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorTransitionMaskImage:backArrowImage];
```

**Updated** use following code it's definitely set back image

```
UIButton *backBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[backBtn setBackgroundImage:backArrowImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(goback) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
backBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 54, 30);
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backBtn] ;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

Comment: I have made amends in my code, that you are providing me. But it does not help me.

Comment: @yashica15 you have use my updated code it's definitely work!!

Comment: This code will definitely work. But I have to paste this code in every ViewController. I want to change it globally from AppDelegate.

Comment: Follow this link: Swift how to change tintColor of backIndicatorImage

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160019/discussion-between-tubelight-and-yashica15).

Answer (score 0):

// untested code

// try to see if you can access the back button directly

```
NSArray *leftBarButtonItems = self.navigationController.navigationBar.items.firstObject.leftBarButtonItems;
for (id barButtonItem in leftBarButtonItems) {
    UIBarButtonItem *item = (UIBarButtonItem*)barButtonItem;
    if (item) {
        item.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
}
```